# Why GCC is required in order to install ruby?

Tags: ruby, gcc

I am trying to install Ruby 1.9.2 in my Mac machine, where I am using OS X 10.7.5. During the installation, the installer asked me to first install GCC. After I got GCC installed, the Ruby installation succeeded.

Why does Ruby depend from GCC?

Comment: What OS are you installing on?

Comment: How are you installing gems if you don't already have Ruby installed?

Comment: Maybe he meant rubygems instead of a specific gem.

Comment: I am installing on Mac osx 10.7.5. Seems to be question is unclear I would like to install ruby gems. while installing it is asking to install GCC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some gems require native C extensions, therefore in order to install these gems, GCC needs to be installed.

Also, if your are installing Ruby from source, then you'll need GCC to compile.